# How to access system property set from teamcity build job in java code

Tags: java, teamcity

How to refer system property set in TeamCity job in java code?

For example I have a system property coming from team city build parameter named `abc`. I want to access it in `.java` file by doing `System.getProperty("abc")`

Comment: Do you have any code you tried so far?